# How to make spines in matplotlib figure visible?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, show, axes

I would like to make the spines in my matplotlib figure visible, but they are not showing up.

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))

ax1.set_title(title+' vs Delinquency', fontsize=20, fontweight='bold')
ax1.set_facecolor('none')
ax1.spines['bottom'].set_color('black')
ax1.spines['left'].set_color('black')
ax1.spines['right'].set_color('black')
ax1=sns.barplot(x=feature, y='proportion', data=data, color='midnightblue')
plt.xticks(rotation=45, fontsize=12)
plt.yticks(fontsize=12)
plt.xlabel(title+' Group', fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('Proportion', fontsize=16, color='midnightblue')

ax2=ax1.twinx()
ax2=sns.lineplot(x=feature, y='default_rate', data=data, color='firebrick')
plt.yticks(fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('Default Rate', fontsize=16, color='firebrick')

plt.grid(None)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: looks like you are using a style that hides the spines by default. Try using `sns.set_style("ticks")` a the top of you script? See https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/aesthetics.html?highlight=styles